# How to pass a php variable as wget url?

Tags: php

I want to download a file to my webserver using system (wget)

The following example code works fine.

```
<?php 

chdir('/download directory');

system('wget https://www.win-rar.com/fileadmin/winrar-versions/winrar/winrar-x64-571.exe');
?>
```

I want to pass a php variable to wget instead of giving the url.

ie, I need to do something like below:

```
<?php 

chdir('/download directory');

$myurl = 'wget https://www.win-rar.com/fileadmin/winrar-versions/winrar/winrar-x64-571.exe';

system('wget $myurl');
?>
```

But this is not working. Please correct me.

Comment: Does `system("wget $myurl");` work? (Variables don't get replaced using single quotes). Also, I'd remove `wget` from `$myurl` first

Comment: system("wget $myurl");  worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just be aware, if $myurl comes from user input, it is very vulnerable to injection.  For example, `$myurl = 'http://www.google.com; rm -Rf /tmp';`